Error al conectar DataGrid con Base de Datos MySql, eh visto varios videos pero ninguno me resulve el error ya que son diferente conexion a BD
Al ejecutar me sale este problema

CLASE conexionDAL
//SobreCarga //Metodo insert,delete, update
public bool ejecutarComandoSinRetornoDatos(MySqlCommand SQlComando) {
  try {
    MySqlCommand comando = SQlComando;
    comando.Connection = this.EstablecerConexion();
    Conexion.Open();
    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Conexion.Close();
    return true;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
}
/* Select (retorno datos) */
public DataSet EjecutarSentencia(MySqlCommand sqlComando) {
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    MySqlDataAdapter Adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    try {
      MySqlCommand Comando = new MySqlCommand();
      Comando = sqlComando;
      Comando.Connection = EstablecerConexion();
      Adaptador.SelectCommand = Comando;
      Conexion.Open();
      Adaptador.Fill(DS);
      Conexion.Close();
      return DS;
    } catch {
      return DS;
    }
}

CLASE categoriasDAL
public DataSet MostrarCategorias() {
    MySqlCommand sentencia = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id_categoria, nombre_categoria FROM categorias");
    return conexion.EjecutarSentencia(sentencia);
  } 


Agrega un punto de interrupción en los catch y mira si salta una excepción

Por favor, elimina totalmente los try catch, que no tienen ningun sentido asi como estan escritos, y pasa el error que va a salir cuando lo hagas.
